# OpenGL ES 2.0 blending

Tags: opengl-es-2.0, glblendfunc

I set glBlendFunc to

```
glEnable(GL_BLEND);
glBlendFunc(GL_ONE, GL_ONE_MINUS_SRC_ALPHA);
```

and for testing purposes I set the color in my fragment shader like this

```
gl_FragColor = vec4(1.0,0.0,0.0,0.0);
```

Shouldn't the object be fully transparent? What could the reason be if it's not?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The first argument of `glBlendFunc()` is the source factor, the second is the destination factor. In your case:

```
sfactor = 1.0;
dfactor = 1.0 - src.alpha;
```

being `src.alpha = 0.0`, from your `gl_FragColor`:

```
sfactor = 1.0;
dfactor = 1.0;
```

So the color put to the buffer will be:

```
buffer = sfactor * src + dfactor * dst;
```

Substituting...

```
buffer = (1.0,0.0,0.0,0.0) + dst;
```

So, putting it simple, you are adding 1 to the red channel of the existing buffer.

If you want to make the output fully transparent, the usual function is:

```
glBlendFunc(GL_ALPHA, GL_ONE_MINUS_SRC_ALPHA);
```

The one you wrote is usually used for pre-multiplied alpha in the source. But (1, 0, 0, 0) is obviously not a premultiplied alpha value!